# NonlinearStateSpaceModel: Trying to parse the documentation

Tags: control-systems

I am trying to follow the documentation on `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` [here](http://tinyurl.com/qcnwzut), and the first basic example throws me for a loop.  It says it's defining the nonlinear system

$x_1'(t)=u(t)+x_1(t)x_2(t)$

$x_2'(t)=u(t)x_2(t)$

with output $y(t)=x_1(t)$

The example call is written

```
nsys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{u-x1 x2, u x2+1}, {x1}}, {x1, x2}, u]
```

This appears to be the arity-3 overload for `NonlinearStateSpaceModel`, which, if right, must fit the template

$\textrm{NonlinearStateSpaceModel}[\{f,g\},x,u]$

representing the model

$x'(t)=f(x(t), u(t)), y(t)=g(x(t),u(t))$

That means that

$x$ is `{x1, x2}`

$f$ is `{u - x1*x2, u*x2 + 1}`

$g$ is `{x1}`

which I can only read as

$x_1'(t)=u(t)-x_1(t)x_2(t)$

$x_2'(t)=1+u(t)x_2(t)$

with output $y(t)=x_1(t)$

which doesn't look anything like the system they say they're defining. I've blinked my eyes several times and stared at it for too long. It's either a horrendous cluster of typos or I just don't know how to read these models.

Comment: think you're right. Their input does not fit the description.

Comment: The example text has a couple of typos. It should read $\ldots x_1'(t)=u(t)-x_1(t) x_2(t), x_2'(t)=u(t) x_2(t)+1 \ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this description:
[image]

The input should be

```
nsys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{u + Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2],
 u Subscript[x, 2]}, {Subscript[x, 1]}}, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}, u]
```

and so the result would be

[image]

Comment: Your opinion, then, is that the original must be a cluster of typos?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. Either the text or the code is wrong. They do not match.